# "More/much/few of" vs "more/much/few"

Tags: grammar

Consider the following sentences -

> He is more of a mathematician.
>
> He is more mathematician.
>
> Few of the books are stolen.
>
> Few books are stolen.

I have seen there are *of* constructions and also without *of* construction. Is there any difference in meaning between the two? And when to use one over the other?

Comment: In hurry...so putting a comment. Yes, there is a difference

Comment: @MaulikV Thanks, please explain a bit when you come back.

Answer (score 1):

I will start with the second example as it's bit clearer to me.

### 'Few' and 'Few of the'

When we say 'few books', it means that there were few of them *to begin with*. For instance, if I have only 3 books at home, and they are stolen, I would say *"Few books were stolen from my house".* But if I have 300, and of them 3 were stolen, I would say *"Few of the books were stolen from my house".*

### Now the *nuance* of *'more x'* and *'more of an x'*

> He is more of a mathematician -is okay. 
>  He is more mathematician -is not grammatical because *more* **here** should serve as a comparative word.

It could be...

> He's more ***a*** mathematician than ***a*** [something]

The same logic of the second example applies here but **in an abstract sense**.

Say, you are a teacher by profession but you are also a cook. So, you can say

> I am ***more of*** a cook

In such context, we use the preposition *of* to be a *part of* something.

Another example - are you a cyclist or a swimmer? Mind it, *none* of these is your profession. So, in this case, you *could be* **'more of a cyclist than a swimmer'** 'Of' implies to the part OF whole.

You could be ***more of a cook*** than ***a gardener***. You are neither professionally, but a ***part of both*** as a hobbyist.

[Wish you a very happy new year].

Comment: +1 Nice answer...Thank you for wishing...and a very happy new year to you and your family...